# Trigger PL/SQL Check Multiple Entries

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Okay so I need to create a trigger that checks to see if a reviewer for a movie is rating the same movie twice.

I wrote this:

```
create or replace 
trigger viewer_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON viewer
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
-- create a variable to store the count of rows
counter  number;

BEGIN

--Any reviewer can't review the same movie twice

SELECT count(*) INTO counter
FROM viewer
WHERE "USERID"=:new."USERID";

IF counter = 1
THEN  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR('-20012', 'Constraint Violated!');
END IF;
END;
```

The problem is that when I test it, I am still able to rate for the same movie as the same rater. Is there something that I am not doing?

Comment: Why would you create a trigger for this?  Why would you not create a constraint?  Wouldn't you need to verify that the combination of `USERID` and `MOVIED` is unique?

Comment: you should also add movie column in where clause like 
where userid = new.userid and
movieid = new.movieid

Comment: do NOT use triggers for this. they 100% will not work in an environment where multiple sessions are writing (as one session may not see the rows from the other session if the commit hasn't been done). as Justin says, a simple unique constraint will suffice here.

Comment: Triggers are a terrible idea to enforce constraints. I don't think that even a unique constraint is required, although it's a good idea. Your users will interact with the database through some UI, this validation check could easily be part of a UI level validation (like for example in Oracle forms this validation could be very easy to do).

Comment: @Annjawn, a UI-based validation will suffer from the same problem that a trigger will - it will not account for multiple sessions. A unique constraint is required.

Answer (score 2):

The rule of thumb is

> don't do anything programatic that is already in the DBMS engine

I mean, in your situation, create a unique constraint on (userid, movieid).

```
ALTER TABLE viewer
add CONSTRAINT user_movie_unique UNIQUE (userid, movieid);
```

Document to read: [Constraints and Triggers](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-constraints.html)